# Why are there differences on Debian version information?

Tags: linux, debian

On the same machine if I run `cat /etc/os-release`, I get:

```
cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

But then if I run: `cat /proc/version, I get:

```
cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.16.7-tinycore64 (root@064f0e1ce709) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 20 00:06:13 UTC 2014
```

Please assume that I don't know(!) - can someone please explain the version differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To be Exact:**

> This one show information about the Kernel and [GNU Compiler
>   Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) tools used to build the Kernel.

```
cat /proc/version 
{kernel Version} ({user who compiled}) ({GNU Compiler Collection Version} ({gcc dpkg version}) ) #1 {kernel type} {kernel build date}
```

> This one shows complete information about [Debian Release](https://www.debian.org/releases/).

```
cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Full_Name (Codename)"
NAME="Distribution_Name"
VERSION_ID="Version_Identifier"
VERSION="Version_Number (Codename)"
ID="Short_Name"
HOME_URL="WebSite"
SUPPORT_URL="Support_Site"
BUG_REPORT_URL="Bug_Report_Site"
```